# preg_match -ing from lines in a .txt file (with spaces and brackets!)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I have got this far on my own but It looks like I have found the limit of my PHP knowledge (which isn't very much at all!). This script is for filtering filenames (game roms/iso's etc). It has other ways of filtering too but I've just highlighted the section I'm trying to add. I want a external .txt file I can put names of files in like so (separated by a single line break):

```
Pacman 2 (USA)
Space Invaders (USA)
Asteroids (USA)
Something Else (Europe)
```

And then running the script will search the directory and place any matching filenames in the "removed" folder. It loops fine with all the other filtering techniques it uses. I'm just trying to add my own (unsuccessfully!)

```
$gameList = trim(shell_exec("ls -1"));
$gameArray = explode("\n", $gameList);
$file = file_get_contents('manualremove.txt');
$manualRemovePattern = '/(' . str_replace(PHP_EOL, "|", $file) . ')/';

shell_exec('mkdir -p Removed');

foreach($gameArray as $thisGame) {
if(!$thisGame) continue;
// Probably already been removed
if(!file_exists($thisGame)) continue;

if(preg_match ($manualRemovePattern , $thisGame)) {
echo "{$thisGame} is on the manual remove list. Moving to Removed folder.\n";
shell_exec("mv \"{$thisGame}\" Removed/");
continue;
```

So this is working when I put names of games with no spaces or brackets in the .txt file. But spaces or brackets (or both) are breaking it's functionality. Could someone help me out?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try reading in the file with `$file = fgets('manualremove.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)` and then use the `"/(?:" . implode("|", array_map(function($i) {return preg_quote(trim($i), "/");}, $file)) . ')/'` to build the regex.

Comment: Does that work now?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm not quite sure what to replace!

Comment: See https://ideone.com/yswzbQ

Comment: Edit: OK thanks 1 sec :D

Comment: Aww, I'm getting these errors: https://pastebin.com/f2qZGvkK

Comment: Wait, it is incomplete.

Comment: Ok, use `$file = file_get_contents('manualremove.txt');
$manualRemovePattern = "/(?:" . implode("|", array_map(function($i) {return preg_quote(trim($i), "/");}, explode(PHP_EOL, $file))) . ')/';` - https://ideone.com/xtEqwZ

Comment: Also, please try `$file = file('manualremove.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$manualRemovePattern = "/(?:" . implode("|", array_map(function($i) {return preg_quote(trim($i), "/");}, $file)) . ')/';` - https://ideone.com/Q7KBvq - I think this one should be better.

Comment: Thankyou! I've been looking at this for hours and you've smashed it in seconds, legend! :D :D :D - I need to get better at PHP haha! - EDIT - ok I'll try the 2nd one too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173568/discussion-between-unluckyforsome-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: To match whole strings, use `^` and `$` anchors. Replace `"/(?:"` with `/^(?:'` and `')/'` with `')$/'`.

Comment: Ahh, you meant replace `"/(?:"` with `"/^(?:"` and `")/"` with `")$/"`! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I missed a quote in `"/^(?:"` - you may use both double or single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the fourth line in the code you supplied with

```
$manualRemovePattern = "/(?:" . implode("|", array_map(function($i) {
    return preg_quote(trim($i), "/");
}, explode(PHP_EOL, $file))) . ')/';
```

The main idea is:

- Split the file contents you obtained into lines with `explode(PHP_EOL, $file)`
- Then you need to iterate over the array and modify each item in the array (which can be done with `array_map`)
- Modifying the array items involves adding escaping `\` before any special regex metacharacter and a regex delimiter chosen by you (in this case, `/`), and this is done with `preg_quote(trim($i), "/")`
- Note I remove any leading/trailing spaces with `trim` from the array items - just in case.

To match them as whole words, use *word boundaries*:

```
$manualRemovePattern = '/\b(?:' . implode('|', array_map(function($i) {
    return preg_quote(trim($i), '/');
}, explode(PHP_EOL, $file))) . ')\b/';
```

To match them as whole strings, use `^`/`$` *anchors*:

```
$manualRemovePattern = '/^(?:' . implode('|', array_map(function($i) {
    return preg_quote(trim($i), '/');
}, explode(PHP_EOL, $file))) . ')$/';
```

Comment: I am adding your above code regarding using word boundaries but I think there must be a syntax error somewhere? - I re-tried your original solution and it seems to be working... I think!