# Getting an exact preg_replace match from a .txt file

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a script where a line-seperated list in .txt format (E.G:

```
Summer Heat Beach Volleyball.zip
Beach Volleyball.zip
Pacman.zip
Space Invaders.zip
```

Is used to search every filename in a directory for matches, and those matches are placed in a "Removed" folder.

```
<?php
$gameList = trim(shell_exec("ls -1"));
$gameArray = explode("\n", $gameList);

shell_exec('mkdir -p Removed');
shell_exec('mkdir -p Process');


// Make sure what manualregiondupes.txt is doing
if (file_exists('manualregiondupes.txt'))
{
    $manualRegionDupes = file('manualregiondupes.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $manualRegionPattern = "/(?:" . implode("|", array_map(function ($i)
    {
        return preg_quote(trim($i) , "/");
    }
    , $manualRegionDupes)) . ')/';
    echo "ManualRegeionDupes.txt has been found, ";
    if (trim(file_get_contents('manualregiondupes.txt')) == false)
    {
        echo "but is empty! Continuing without manual region dupes filter.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "and is NOT empty! Applying the manual region dupes filter.\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "ManualRegionDupes.txt has NOT been found. Continuing without the manual region dupes filter.\n";
}


// Do this magic for every file
foreach ($gameArray as $thisGame)
{
    if (!$thisGame) continue;
    // Probably already been removed
    if (!file_exists($thisGame)) continue;

    $niceName = trim(preg_replace('%[\(|\[].*%', '', $thisGame));


    // Filenames in manualregiondupes.txt
    if (file_exists('manualregiondupes.txt'))
    {
        if (trim(file_get_contents('manualregiondupes.txt')) == true)
        {
            if (preg_match($manualRegionPattern, $thisGame))
            {
                echo "{$thisGame} is on the manual region dupes remove list. Moved to Removed folder.\n";
                shell_exec("mv \"{$thisGame}\" Removed/");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Only problem is, if a name like

`Beach Volleyball.zip`

is on the manualregiondupes.txt list, files with a filename like

`Summer Heat Beach Volleyball.zip`

are being snagged by the filter too. How do I perform exact matching?

Comment: I already [suggested `^` and `$` anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963005/preg-match-ing-from-lines-in-a-txt-file-with-spaces-and-brackets#comment88943732_50963005), and you accepted my answer after it. Is that not working? Try using `\b` instead. `'/\b(?:' . implode("|", array_map(function ($i)
    {
        return preg_quote(trim($i) , "/");
    }
    , $manualRegionDupes)) . ')\b/'`

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm a complete begginner and I don't know to put them in!

I tried like this:

`$manualRegionPattern = "/^(?:'" . implode("|", array_map(function ($i)`
`{`
`return preg_quote(trim($i) , "/");`
`}`
`, $manualRegionDupes)) . ')$/'; `

EDIT: OK, I'll try :D thanks!